# pass ip scan through subroutine as an argument

Tags: perl, security

Is it possible to pass an nmap scan of any IP address through as a subroutine?

I am currently executing the scans like so:

('Nmap -v -r xx.xx.xxx.xxx p 1-10); 
Which works but I want to pass it through a subroutine. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the [`Nmap::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/~apersaud/Nmap-Parser-1.21/Parser.pm) module from CPAN.

The syntax seems pretty straightforward:

```
use Nmap::Parser;
my $np = new Nmap::Parser;
$np->parsescan($nmap_path, $nmap_args, @ips);
```